# rsAccessDenied on new reporting services report server link created by the reporting services configuration manager

Tags: reporting-services, configuration, reportserver

On a Windows 7 computer we installed SQL Server 2012 Business with the reporting services.

We tried to use the reporting services configuration manager and chose the default settings for the report server.

We now have a clickable URL link to the report server. When I click on the link that was created, this error message is displayed:

```
Reporting Services Error
The permissions granted to user '<our computer name>\<our admin user>' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied) Get Online Help
SQL Server Reporting Services
```

We also disabled UAC.

The same error is shown when trying:

```
http://localhost/Reports
```

Can you tell us how to grant the needed permissions?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you an Administrator on the computer? If so, what happens when you open the Report Manager URL after opening Internet Explorer with "Run as Administrator"?

Comment: We use Chrome. I just tried to open Chrome as Administrator but the same error is shown. I will now try Internet Explorer to see if the same error is shown.

Comment: Internet Explorer asks for the user and password. After I enter them in we get the same error when running Internet Explorer as Administrator.

Comment: I also turned off UAC as suggested on a web site we looked up previously.

Comment: I just rebooted the computer. I never guessed that a simple reboot would get it working. Anyway, thanks Ian for your quick reply. :-)